# REACT- TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object

Tags: reactjs

*REACTJS learner here*. I am trying to toggle the text via `useReducer` but it doesn't seems to work and I have no idea why. I keep getting the warning message of *cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object*. However, when I remove the style tag `style={listt.list[0].style` in `<h2>` tag. The text `'color=purple'` changed to `'color=red'` and the console log shows the mutated list well. So I have really no idea what is the problem here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the link to codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/state-prob-cd21c?file=/src/Toggle.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

function Texting() {
  const state = {
    list: [{ name: "I am awesome", style: { color: "purple" } }],
  };

  function reducer(listt, action) {
    switch (action) {
      case "toggle":
        const clone = [...listt.list]; //clone is new copy
        clone[0].style.color = "red";
        console.log(clone);
        return { ...listt, list: clone };
    }
  }
  const [listt, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, state);
  console.log("new list is " + JSON.stringify(listt.list[0].style));
  return (
    <div>
      Color = {listt.list.map((x) => x.style.color)}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch("toggle")}>toggle!</button>
      <h2 style={listt.list[0].style}>
        Why Error : TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of
        object
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Texting;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide new `style` object to `clone`. Try following:

```
clone[0].style = {color : "red"};
```

Since your `style` object contains only `color` property, you can use above code. If in case it contains multiple properties use following

```
clone[0].style = {...clone[0].style, color : "red"};
```

**Note**: These solutions are specific to the code that you have provided. But in live project we don't specify hard coded `indexes` values

Comment: Thank you for your response. May I know why it doesn't work that way ? Since I am able to change the text by that.. thanks

Comment: Even if you have cloned the array the reference for style object is still pointing to the style object of state, which you can not modify directly. Hence you need to change is reference by creating new object. If the solution which i have provided works for you, you can accept the answer.